# HTML 5 Video OnEnded Event not Firing

Tags: html, html5-video, jquery

I'm trying to react to the HTML 5 `onended` event for the `video` tag without success.  In the code snippet below I added the mouseleave event to be sure the jQuery code is correct and that event does activate the `alert()` box.

The video plays just fine but I am not receiving the `onended` event (my `alert()` does not fire).

Testing in Chrome, updated today to version 5.0.375.55.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myVideoTag").bind('mouseleave onended', function(){
        alert("All done, function!");
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="myVideoTag" width="640" height="360" poster="Fractal-zoom-1-04-Snowflake.jpg" controls>
    <source src="Fractal-zoom-1-04-Snowflake.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="Fractal-zoom-1-04-Snowflake.ogg" type="video/ogg"></source>
</video>

<body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you're binding to the `ended` event instead of `onended`, always leave the `on` out when binding with jQuery, for example you couldn't do `.on("onclick")`, you'd do `.on("click")`.

If it helps, there's a full listing of available events for the `<video>` element here: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: Also remember that the event won't get fired on ie9 mobile for Windows Phone Mobile.

Comment: Two years later and it's still a draft spec `Editor's Draft 26 June 2012`

Comment: Make that 3 years later: Editor's Draft 30 July 2013

Comment: Four. Editor's Draft 22 June 2014

Comment: 2016 reporting. No longer a draft :P

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the answer for this too. Here's what worked for me in for the jQuery mobile framework:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#idname").bind('ended', function(){
  $.mobile.changePage($('#idofpageyouwantogoto'), 'fade');
  });
});
```