# How to apply onEnded event for HTML video tag

Tags: jquery, html, video, flowplayer

I have tried the video tag with flowplayer. The code is given below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!-- 2. flowplayer -->
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

<!-- 3. skin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/skin/minimalist.css" />
<div class="player" data-engine="flash"  style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 200px; height: 150px; " >

<video preload="none" poster="images.jpeg" id="vid">
  <source type="video/webm" src="file4.webm"/>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="file2.mp4"/>
  <source type="video/ogg" src="file2.ogv"/>
</video>
</div>

 <script>
 // run script after document is ready
 $(function () {

// install flowplayer to an element with CSS class "player"
  var player=  $(".player").flowplayer({
   swf: "flowplayer-5.4.0.swf"
       });



});

player.load(function() {
    alert("player was loaded programmatically");
});
</script>
```

How can I redirect the page to http://google.com if the video is finished? How can I fire a ended event for detecting the video end?
Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.4.0/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Master function, encapsulates all functions
        function init() {
            var video = document.getElementById("vid");

     video.onended = function(e) {

    alert('ok');
    // code to navigate page
    }
   }
    </script>
<script>
 $(function () {

   // install flowplayer to an element with CSS class "player"
  var player=  $(".player").flowplayer({
   swf: "flowplayer-5.4.0.swf"
       });



 });

  </script>


  <a class="player" data-engine="flash"  style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 200px; height: 150px; " >

 <video preload="none" poster="images.jpeg" id="vid">
  <source type="video/webm" src="file4.webm"/>
  <source type="video/mp4" src="file2.mp4"/>
  <source type="video/ogg" src="file2.ogv"/>
 </video>
</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect when an HTML5 video finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741493/detect-when-an-html5-video-finishes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// make a server call each time a clip starts or finishes
$f("#myPlayer").onStart(function(clip) {
    $.get("statistics.php?action=start&clip=" + clip.url);
}).onFinish(function(clip) {
    $.get("statistics.php?action=finish&clip=" + clip.url);
});
```

Check [This](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/scripting.html) for more info

**Update**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // Master function, encapsulates all functions
            function init() {
                var video = document.getElementById("vid");   

    video.onended = function(e) {

        alert('ok');
        // code to navigate page
        } 
}
        <script>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have changed my code as above. But it doesn't work though!

Comment: The above code which I used for playing videos in IOS. So I can't play the videos without that div. You mean I need to remove the div and add the class="player" to video tag, right?

Comment: Naa.. Its should be <a> tag and you need to use http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html javascript api for the technique I mentioned

Comment: If you are using html5 tags then there may alternate choices wait I look into that

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been working 2 days with this problem!

Comment: I need to use Html5 for all ios devices, otherwise it won't display videos

Comment: I have edited the java script with player.load, but doesn't work

Comment: I have updated the code its confusing you mixing video tags and flow player.. Note the above code may not work in all browsers

Comment: :( I have updated the code as above. but I didn't get an alert!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218752/trigger-changepage-when-html5-video-ends-ios

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this answer?
[HTML 5 Video OnEnded Event not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925851/html-5-video-onended-event-not-firing)

Also you can try checking the 'ended' property of video every few milliseconds
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp

```
function checkIfEnded( )
{
  myVid=document.getElementById("video1");
  //alert(myVid.ended);
  if ( !myVid.ended )
  {
    setTimeout( "checkIfEnded( )", 1000);
  }
  else
  {
    //goto google.com
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code from w3schools. But I am always getting false. That is because I am using a div for flow player. How can I change it to working condition?

Comment: @NewPHP just checked here http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html, Please check the 'finished' property of your player object periodically.