# How to play video only when it had downloaded completely?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am making web page that will sequentially plays video from server on big screen. I set "auto" value for *preload* attribute of **video** tag. I want the video begins to play only when video had downloaded completely. Is there any ways to do such thing?

In the *events summary* of media elements from html5 standart I didn't find neccessary event.

Comment: If you're using an HTML5 library, they usually have excellent features to help out with things like that.  Youtube API also checks how much of the video is loaded.

Comment: @David Hobs Thanks, but in this case for me it is better to avoid using of libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#mediaevents) you can use `progress` event. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994680/accessing-html-5-video-progress-event-with-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029519/html5-video-percentage-loaded) are some examples how to use it. Every time when `progress` event is fired check if video is loaded and if so, play it.