# Embedded Vimeo Video Callbacks

Tags: jquery, video, vimeo, html5-video

This post is kind of a follow up to a post I made earlier in regards to [HTML5 video callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954595/html5-video-callbacks). In that thread, I was given a great piece of code that would allow for the browser to be informed of when the video stops playing and then fire off an action (with jQuery). This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$('video.normal').bind('ended', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut().queue(function(){ 
        $(this).siblings('.post-video').fadeIn();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Which basically fades the video out when it's completed and brings a poster frame of the video (or similar image) back into view.

Well, the scope of the project has changed and now the client is asking for true full screen video and different size videos to be delivered based on user connection speed, something that's a little over my head and a lot over budget. So I've been researching and a Vimeo Plus player seems like a great alternative for visitors using a desktop browser (HD embeds, true full screen, and more). Thing is, I need that above code to continue working in some capacity or another, so does the embedded Vimeo player offer a similar callback that I can utilize? Or am I SOL here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vimeo's staff didn't give me explicit examples of how to do this, but they did point be in the direction of Moogaloop, which is the name of their video player found here: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/moogaloop --- Any ideas where I can take it from here?  Their examples utilize SWFobject and Mootools, two libraries I'm currently not using nor want to include. Any ideas on how to get this working with just jQuery or simple javascript?

Comment: Check out this example: https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-api-examples/blob/master/moogaloop-api/javascript/froogaloop.html which uses that moogaloop API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo's "Universal Embed Code" fires lots of useful events, among them `finish`.
They've changed their API quite a lot recently, so there are lots of outdated docs out there.

Here's their up-to-date [API Documentation](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api), [playground](http://player.vimeo.com/playground) and [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript).  SWFObject or MooTools are not needed.