# Video playing in canvas won't let me click controls(pause, play, sound etc)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Video playing in canvas won't let me click controls(pause, play, sound etc)

How do i make controls accessible whilst keeping same functions and animation. Animations work fine etc and functions.

Code:

```
<style>
               #cvs {
                   position: absolute; 
                   top: 0px;
                   left: 0px;
               }
           </style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var context;
            var text = "";
            var textDirection ="";

            $(function()
            {
                context = document.getElementById("cvs").getContext("2d");            
                setInterval("animate()", 360);

                textDirection ="right";
                textXpos = 5;
                text = "This is my video..";    
            });  

            function animate() {            
                // Clear screen
                context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                context.globalAlpha = 1;
            //context.fillStyle = '#fff';
            //  context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);    

                var metrics = context.measureText(text);
                var textWidth = metrics.width;
                if (textDirection == "right") {
                    textXpos += 10;

                    if (textXpos > 500 - textWidth) {
                        textDirection = "left";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    textXpos -= 10;

                    if (textXpos < 10) {
                        textDirection = "right";
                    }                    
                }

                context.font = '20px _sans';
                context.fillStyle = 'white';
                context.textBaseline = 'top';
                context.fillText  ( text, textXpos, 440);    
              }  
              </script>
          </head>
          <body> 
             <div id="page">
        <video id="video" autoplay loop>
          <source id='mp4'
            src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
            type='video/mp4'>
          <source id='webm'
            src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm"
            type='video/webm'>
          <source id='ogv'
            src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
            type='video/ogg'>
          <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
        </video>
                <canvas id="cvs" width="500" height="500">
                   Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
                </canvas>
             </div>
          </body>
       </html>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jBHCN/14/

Comment: Very nice animation. Where are the controls?

Comment: It's normal because the canvas is front of the video

Comment: this is your third question about the exact same thing :) I suggest re-envision it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have the controls on the canvas.

Make custom controls on the canvas that control the movie.

See here : [How to control HTML5 video with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988144/how-to-control-html5-video-with-javascript)

and here: http://www.broken-links.com/2009/10/06/building-html5-video-controls-with-javascript/