# Video alterations javascript, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, video

Using the following coding

```
<video width="100%" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Is it possible to make the video stop playing after the first time, and to have the video fill the webpage area

I have no experience in using JQuery or JWplayer, so if the best option is using these languages and objects, please give as much help as possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as making it play fullscreen, you can find more information here: [fullscreen video tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen). Setting the tag to autoplay should only make it play once. Adding the ["loop" parameter](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp) would make it repeat.

Comment: When I use the following coding, it has no effect with or with out using 'loop' it still repeats                                                       <video autoplay='true' loop='false'>
       <source src="Website Opening.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

Comment: Try moving the source into the video element as an attribute http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_video_tag.cfm

Comment: Thankyou that worked, Is it possible to make the video dissapear after it has been played once?

Comment: Here's an example I found for doing that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954595/html5-video-callbacks