# jQuery: Incorrect use of variables on video function

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Tying to play videos but The use of my variables are not working.

- First video play only once, when stops second video starts.
- Second video plays and loops.
- Video should play smoothly with no gaps and no jumps.

**My Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/654geqvp/1/

```js
var start = [
    "http://praegnanz.de/html5video/player/video_SD.webm",
    "http://praegnanz.de/html5video/player/video_SD.webm",
    "http://praegnanz.de/html5video/player/video_SD.mp4"];

var loop = [
    "http://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.webm",
    "http://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.theora.ogv",
    "http://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v"];

    var curSrc = 0;
    $(function() {
      $('#start').attr(start, start[curSrc % start.length]);
      curSrc++;
      var video = $('#start').get(0);

      $('#start').on('loadedmetadata', function() {
        video.currentTime = 0.01;
        video.play();
      }).on('ended', function() {
        //console.log('ended');
        video.loop = loop[curSrc % loop.length];
        video.load();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="start" style="width:100%;"></video>
```

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl not sure what you mean, Even locally doesn't work

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl even with the absolute paths doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked this out?: [*MSDN: Using JavaScript to control the HTML5 video player*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, you do not need to link to JSFiddle anymore, Stack Overflow has embedded snippets for JavaScript.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl thanks, yes that's brilliant. good to know. Would u be able to help me with this plaese? I'm not able to find a solution

Comment: See: [*How do you detect HTML5 video events?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2954618/1762224). Try to replace `on('ended')` with `bind('ended')`. You could also try [attaching the event natively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741527/1762224): `$('#start')[0].onended = function(e){};`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl not sure where $('#start')[0].onended = function(e){}; goes

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/654geqvp/2/ ? bust still doesn't work.

Comment: [`Video.loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-loop) is a boolean value, not a string. I cannot assist you further. You need to read up some more on the Video object. Try to code in pure JavaScript first, get that to work and then try using jQuery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69210/discussion-between-user3699998-and-mr-polywhirl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I changed some variable names around. You need to set the `loop` attribute on the video to true. You can remove the `controls` attribute it you wish. I converted the original to a jQuery plugin.

To get rid of the black flash when transitioning videos, you can set the `poster` attribute of the video element to be the first frame of the second video.

```js
$.fn.videoLoop = function(options) {
  var video = $(this),
    videoEl = video.get(0),
    selVideoIdx = 0;

  options = options || {};

  var playlist = options.playlist || [],
    // Use a white background by default if a poster is not provided. This
    // should prevent the transition from showing a black screen. If possible,
    // use the first frame of the looping video or a solid color to match
    // the backdrop of the video.
    poster = options.poster || "http://placehold.it/1024x768/FFFFFF/FFFFFF";

  if (playlist.length > 1) {
    video.attr('src', playlist[selVideoIdx % playlist.length]);
    video.attr('poster', poster);
    video.attr('autoload', true);
    selVideoIdx++;

    video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
      videoEl.currentTime = 0.5;
      videoEl.play();
    }).bind('ended', function() {
      videoEl.src = playlist[selVideoIdx % playlist.length];
      videoEl.loop = true;
      videoEl.load();
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  $('#start').videoLoop({
    'playlist': [
      '../video-start/Homepage_video_ref_v01.mp4',
      '../video-loop/7_Sec_Loop_v01.mp4'
    ],
    'poster': "http://placehold.it/1024x768/6DBBD2/6DBBD2"
  });
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 100%;
  background: #53abc5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="start" controls="controls"></video>
```