# Trigger play for HTML 5 video only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

Im using a script to play a html5 video once an element is in viewport. Once the video is played I want it to remain paused, but once I start scrolling the video start playing again. Any idea how to trigger play only once?

Script:

```
jQuery.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

jQuery(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    if (jQuery('.videoblock').isInViewport()) {
jQuery('video.full_screen_sections_video').trigger('play');
    } 
});
```

Edit: I added `jQuery(this).removeClass('videoblock');` to my the function. This solves it, not sure of thats the best way to do it?

Comment: you can add an else condition and pause the video when not in viewport.
And best way to remove class is inside the ended callback
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954595/html5-video-callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the event listener which is starting the video after it is in viewport:

```js
jQuery(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    if (jQuery('.videoblock').isInViewport()) {
      jQuery('video.full_screen_sections_video').trigger('play');
      // Remove the event listener once the video is started
      jQuery(window).off('resize scroll');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding **jQuery(this).removeClass('videoblock');** will remove the **videoblock** class from the element that is in the viewport, which will prevent the **if** condition from being true on subsequent scrolls. However, this solution may not be the most efficient, as it modifies the DOM on every scroll event, which can slow down the performance of your page.

A more efficient solution would be to use a flag variable to keep track of whether the video has already been played or not. Here's an example code :

```
 var videoPlayed = false;

  jQuery(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  if (jQuery('.videoblock').isInViewport() && !videoPlayed) {
   jQuery('video.full_screen_sections_video').trigger('play');
   videoPlayed = true;
  }
  });
```

In this code, the **videoPlayed** variable is initialized to **false**. When the video is played for the first time, the **videoPlayed** variable is set to **true**, and the video won't play again on subsequent scrolls because the **if** condition will fail. This solution avoids modifying the DOM on every scroll event, which should improve the performance of your page.