# javascript callback works with IE, but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, callback

I think this code should play a sound, then show an alert box. It works with IE9, but with Chrome & Firefox, the sound is played, but the callback is never called - so no alert box.

I'm a c#, c++ programmer new to javascript, and I could use some help! Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var playAll= function(){
             var audio = document.getElementById('s');

             var callback = function(e){
                alert("ended"); 
             };

            audio.onended = callback;
            audio.play();
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input name="Button1" type="button" value="Play" onclick="playAll()"/>

    <audio ID="s">
    <source src="s.mp3"  >
    <source src="s.ogg"  >
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure that it is not an issue of invalid html, use the following valid version

```
<audio ID="s">
  <source src="s.mp3" />
  <source src="s.ogg" />
</audio>
```

and then use the correct way to bind events.

```
audio.addEventListener( "ended", callback, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

`onended` seems to be specific to IE9, Chrome and Firefox will fire the event `ended`, which you can bind a function to like so: `v.addEventListener("ended", function() { alert("ended"); }`

Remember that the HTML5 spec is still being developed, and not all browsers implement it the same way.

There's a similar question here: [HTML 5 Video OnEnded Event not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925851/html-5-video-onended-event-not-firing)

Comment: Thanks! That code works with IE & Chrome, but to get it to work with Firefox, I had to add the 'false' parameter: audio.addEventListener("ended", function(e) { alert("ended"); },false);