# HTML5 video onended not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html5-video

This doesn't seem to work in chrome, it works in firefox. Is there a fix for it? Could I instead say when it reaches 20 seconds which is the length of the video that it should execute something somehow?

```
v.onended = function(e) {
    alert('video ended');
    $("video").animate({'opacity':0});
    $('#play').removeClass('pause');
}
```

Comment: It started to fail me just today. I don't know if it was an update from chrome. In MS Edge 38.14393 and Firefox 52.0  is working correctly.  My current chrome version is Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Answer (score -3):

In Chrome, try binding to `ended` instead of `onended` when using jQuery, as described here: [HTML 5 Video OnEnded Event not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925851/html-5-video-onended-event-not-firing)